# How to parse this JSON response with GSON after a Retrofit GET request?

Tags: android, json, rest, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to parse a JSON response using GSON after a Retrofit GET request. I don't need all the keys and values so I only @Expose the ones that I need and instructed the parser to do so. The request fires OK and the response come clean, but looking into logcat I found this error which evidently points me that POJO model is bad formatted or implemented:

**04-09 12:16:01.679    5604-5604/? V/Retrofit error﹕ retrofit.converter.ConversionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

This is the JSON response (which returns ok after GET request):

```
{
   objects: [
   {
     rating: 0.97,
     name: "High Line",
     ranking: 0,
     url: "http://www.thehighline.org",
     price: null,
     phone: "2125006035",
     last_sync: 1428328869,
     photos: [
    "https://irs3.4sqi.net/img/general/original/11402168_2zKtnTfWXPJJJAaX7N6g1EMPTR7ahNqSAOsMotN-jNU.jpg"
     ],
     local_id: 13778,
     likes: 0,
     city_id: 2621,
     address: "btwn Gansevoort & W 34th St",
     resource_uri: "/api/v1/venues/40f1d480f964a5206a0a1fe3/",
     id: "40f1d480f964a5206a0a1fe3",
     categories: [
     {
       name: "Park",
       parent: {
            local_id: 7,
            name_id: "sights",
            name: "Landmarks",
           id: "4d4b7105d754a06377d81259"
       },
       local_id: 494,
       name_id: "park",
       category_id: 7,
       id: "4bf58dd8d48988d163941735"
    }
   ],
   location: {
      lat: 40.7470618874989,
      lng: -74.0051937103271
   }
  },
  {
    rating: 0.97,
    name: "Central Park",
    ranking: 0,
    url: "http://www.centralparknyc.org",
    price: null,
    phone: "2123106600",
    last_sync: 1428521923,
    photos: [
  "https://irs2.4sqi.net/img/general/original/655018_Zp3vA90Sy4IIDApvfAo5KnDItoV0uEDZeST7bWT-qzk.jpg"
    ],
    local_id: 13826,
    likes: 0,
    city_id: 2621,
    address: "59th St to 110th St",
    resource_uri: "/api/v1/venues/412d2800f964a520df0c1fe3/",
    id: "412d2800f964a520df0c1fe3",
    categories: [
    {
       name: "Park",
       parent: {
          local_id: 7,
          name_id: "sights",
          name: "Landmarks",
          id: "4d4b7105d754a06377d81259"
       },
       local_id: 494,
       name_id: "park",
       category_id: 7,
       id: "4bf58dd8d48988d163941735"
     }
    ],
    location: {
      lat: 40.7888599444948,
      lng: -73.9611625671387
    }
   }
 ],
  meta: {
    total_count: 1344,
    next: "/api/v1/venues/?city_id=2621&category=topPicks&offset=2&limit=2&format=json",
    limit: 2,
    offset: 0
    }
}
```

This is the main activity call to the Retrofit service:

```
   Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("city_id", "2621");
    params.put("offset", "0");
    params.put("limit", "2"); 
    params.put("category", "topPicks");
    params.put("format", "json");


    ApiClient.getApiClient().listVenues(params, new Callback<List<ApiResponse>>() {

        @Override
        public void success(List<ApiResponse> venues, Response response) {

            //consumir venues
            Log.v("RETROFIT SUCCESS", response.getBody().toString());

            mAdapter = new MainCustomAdapter(venues);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {

            if (retrofitError.getResponse() != null) {
                Log.v("Retrofit error", retrofitError.getCause().toString());
            }
            //manejar el fallo


        }
    });
```

This is the Api client:

```
public class ApiClient {
private static ApiVenuesInterface apiVenues;

public static ApiVenuesInterface getApiClient() {

   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

    if (apiVenues == null) {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()

                .setEndpoint("http://endpoint.com")
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setLog(new AndroidLog("RETROFIT"))
                .build();

        apiVenues = restAdapter.create(ApiVenuesInterface.class);
    }

    return apiVenues;
}

 public interface ApiVenuesInterface {
     //llamada asíncrona al querystring de venues
     @GET("/api/v1/venues")
     void listVenues(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params, Callback<List<ApiResponse>> callback);
}}
```

And finally this my POJO model (which I believe is the place where the main problem is):

```
    public class ApiResponse {
    private List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

}
class Object {

    @Expose
    private String name;
    @Expose
    private List<String> photos = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Expose
    private String address;
    @Expose
    private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The photos
     */
    public List<String> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The address
     */
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The categories
     */
    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    class Category {
        @Expose
        private String name;

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * The name
         */
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

    }}
```

So, how did I must to model my POJO to parse the data I need? Thanks in advance.

**IMPORTANT EDIT: This question is valid for Retrofit 1.x. Be aware that Retrofit 2.x is a little bit different than this because it uses annotations and Call methods.**

Comment: Based on a quick look, your `Callback` return type isn't of type `List<ApiResponse>`, but rather just `ApiResponse`. Could you try changing it to `Callback<ApiResponse>` and see what happens? Right now you're telling Gson to convert the response in a list/array of `ApiResponse` objects, but in reality it's an `ApiResponse` object with a list/array of items. You modelled the POJOs correctly, but not so much the retrofit callback.

Comment: Ohhh. I see. I modified the Callback type and it worked. The new thing is that now I'm a little bit confused on how to use ApiResponse now to get the exposed values. Please...can you move your comment to a response so I can accept it?. Thank you @MH!

Comment: Glad to hear! I've added the comment as answer and also made an attempt to answer your follow up question (if you haven't already figured it out by yourself). Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per earlier comment:

Based on a quick look, your `Callback` return type isn't of type `List<ApiResponse>`, but rather just `ApiResponse`. If you change the following, things should start working:

```
public interface ApiVenuesInterface {
     //llamada asíncrona al querystring de venues
     @GET("/api/v1/venues")
     void listVenues(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params, Callback<ApiResponse> callback);
}
```

At the moment, you're telling Gson to convert the response into a list of `ApiResponse` objects, but in reality it's just a single `ApiResponse` wrapping a list/array of items. You modelled the POJOs correctly, but not so much the retrofit callback.

---

[edit] answering your follow up question: you can access the wrapped objects by simply adding a getter to your `ApiResponse` class:

```
public List<Object> getObjects() {
    return objects;
}
```

A small tip: it would be good to come up with a different name for your `Object` class, since its name is identical to the 'mother' of all objects in Java: `java.lang.Object`. This is bound to lead to confusion and very prone to importing/referencing errors. Try to come up with something a little more descriptive, for example `Venue` (as it appears that's what you're dealing with, although I may be mistaken).

---

[edit2] Gson produces an `ApiResponse` object, which wraps around a `List<Object>`. Iterating over that list can be done like any other Java iteration; i.e. using the enhanced for-loop:

```
for (Object object : getObjects()) {
    // get the name for this object
    String name = object.getName();
    // get the address for this object
    String address = object.getAddress();
    // get all the photo urls for this object
    List<String> photos = object.getPhotos();
    // etc...
}
```

The reason you're seeing i.e. `myjavapackage.Object@3c4a86e1` is because Java doesn't know how to represent your objects as a string for printing. You can change this representation by overriding the following method in your `Object` class:

```
@Override public String toString() {
    // return a string representation for this object; i.e. its name:
    return name;
}
```

I'd still recommend to rename your `Object` class to something more sensible to avoid confusing it with the built-in `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Well, I added the getObjects() inmediatly after I reached success in callback. The problem is that I ended with an array of objects like this [myjavapackage.Object@3c4a86e1, myjavapackage.Object@13da2c06]. I don't know how to iterate that array of objects that GSON produces and how to get the items names. Any hint, appreciated.

Comment: @MartinRevert: I added another edit to my answer. This is pretty basic Java stuff though, so it may be worth reading over some of the fundamentals before throwing yourself into the deep. Just a thought.

Answer (score -2):

Try to remove this part  from json string

> {
>   objects:

and last curly bracket.

Comment: Hmmm. I've think there must be a way to parse this without having to modify the web service response and using 'objects' to identify the array of potential objects returned by the api.