# android- Getting json values using gson and retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

Iam using retrofit for http calls and gson for json parsing. I referred these links: [a-smart-way-to-use-retrofit](http://blog.robinchutaux.com/blog/a-smart-way-to-use-retrofit/) and [deserializing-inner-class-when-using-gson-and-retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542692/how-to-parse-this-json-response-with-gson-after-a-retrofit-get-request). But iam getting `retrofit.converter.ConversionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

**This is my json response:**

```
{
    "Document": [
        {
            "Name": "name",
            "Password": "passwrd"
        }
    ]
}
```

**This is my rest api:**

```
@GET("/ObjectTracking/login.php/")
public void getSimpleResponse(@Query("username") String username,
                              @Query("pwd") String password,
                              Callback<SimpleResponseHandler> handlerCallback);
```

**This is my restadapter:**

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .create();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();
```

**MainActivity.class:**

```
simpleRestApi.getSimpleResponse(email, password, new Callback<SimpleResponseHandler>() {
        @Override
        public void success(SimpleResponseHandler simpleResponseHandlers, Response response) {
            Log.e("RETROFIT SUCCESS", response.getBody().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("Retrofit error", error.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
```

**SimpleResponseHandler.class:**

```
public class SimpleResponseHandler {

    @Expose
    private List<Credentials> credentialList= new ArrayList<Credentials>();

    public List<Credentials> getCredentials() {
        return credentialList;
    }

    public void setCredentials(List<Credentials> credentialList) {
        this.credentialList = credentialList;
    }

    public class Credentials {

        @Expose
        private String mName;

        @Expose
        private String mPassword;

        public String getName() {
            return mName;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.mName = name;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return mPassword;
        }

        public void setPassword(String pwd) {
            this.mPassword = pwd;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a parsing error. Try to use a proper annotation to your Credential variables, like @SerializedName("Name") and @SerializedName("Password") because this is proper naming. Then in your SimpleResponseHandler class give another annotation to List<Credential> credentialList and give it @SerializedName("Document") and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java object field names should match json tag name or use @SerializedName()

```
public class Document {

        @Expose @SerializedName("Name")
        private String mName;

        @Expose @SerializedName("Password")
        private String mPassword;
}
```

Java Response Object

```
public class SimpleResponse {

    @Expose @SerializedName("Document")
    private List<Document> credentialList= new ArrayList<Document>();

    public List<Document> getCredentials() {
        return credentialList;
    }

    public void setCredentials(List<Document> credentialList) {
        this.credentialList = credentialList;
    }
    }
```

updated api method

```
@GET("/ObjectTracking/login.php/")
public void getSimpleResponse(@Query("username") String username,
                              @Query("pwd") String password,
                              Callback<List<SimpleResponse>> handlerCallback);
```

Comment: Well, but what if another attribute comes in a way? In addition to "Document". I think that answer that you had written before you edited your post was better.

Comment: I tried this without @Expose annotation and still got exceptions. Anyway I'll try your answer and reply. Thanks.

Comment: @r7v I tried your answer but still getting the same exception.

Comment: I missed the @SerializedName() for document. I have updated the answer. try now

Comment: Its not working. I think the problem is with the json I get as response.

Comment: try to use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to form your java objects. It gives you an easy way to create you java objects mapping json objects

Comment: The problem was that i test on a free hosting server which included analytics script along with the json response. That's why i was not able to parse it. Sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use : [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) for generating pojo from JSON. Here's the appropriate `SimpleResponseHandler` class :

```
public class SimpleResponseHandler {

@SerializedName("Document")
@Expose
private List<Document> document = new ArrayList<Document>();

/**
*
* @return
* The document
*/
public List<Document> getDocument() {
return document;
}

/**
*
* @param document
* The document
*/
public void setDocument(List<Document> document) {
this.document = document;
}

public class Document {

    @Expose
    private String Name;
    @Expose
    private String Password;

    /**
    *
    * @return
    * The Name
    */
    public String getName() {
    return Name;
    }

    /**
    *
    * @param Name
    * The Name
    */
    public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
    }

    /**
    *
    * @return
    * The Password
    */
    public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
    }

    /**
    *
    * @param Password
    * The Password
    */
    public void setPassword(String Password) {
    this.Password = Password;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: @Sree14 are you sure that you're getting the right json response ?

Comment: I am getting the same response I posted above